# JAX-RS + jersy persistence

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, persistence, jax-rs

I am creating a Rest Server using JAX-RS (Jersy) + Spring. My DB layer is MySQL.

What would be the best way to store my data in my DB? Is there any alternative to Hibernate? I have never worked in Hibernate but there seems to be a lot of XML files and configuration.

It would be easier to use Grails or ROR instead. Can anyone point me out a better solution to persist my data in the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into using the hibernate annotations rather than the XML files. They allow you to skip a lot of the XML configuration stuff and configure in line in your models.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernate-3-annotations

http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/02/hibernate-annotations

I think this would probably be easier than making calls to another web framework such as RoR.

Answer (score 2):

If you also have Spring for your db layer, try this example using **spring + hibernate 4**.
http://blog.springsource.org/2012/04/06/migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1/
The code in example is in github.  I also included the link here:
https://github.com/michaelisvy/hibernate-4-spring-3.1-samples

Or alternative, you can look into mybatis, here is a link for **spring + mybatis**.
http://anirbanchowdhury.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/spring-mybatis-integration-part-1/